# Architecture guidance for a Rabbitmq .net implementation

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, rabbitmq

I'm looking for some implementation guidance.  What are the pro and cons of using the wcf bindings or using the plain vanilla .net rabbitmq api. Are the moment we are not constrained to  use either.  I new to rabbitmq, but done a bundle of wcf.

We have a product which collects info from publishers on each device. The product is behind the firewall (at the moment). The publisher will need 3-4 channels.

- Request/Response to publish the metric to publish/subscribe on server with ack from server.
- Update channel, to update publisher rulebase for metric discovery from server.
- Heartbeat channel to check server is up and respond to server heartbeat.
- Possible dead letter channel.

Publisher will be cross platform. Thinking of hosting on Mono, on Linux, BSD, Solaris, Android, MacOs, iOS, and possibly Aix/HP-UX. Don’t know how effective wcf endpoints would be in these instances.

Server will have multiple workers, each receive same message from own? queue, ack it and process it against their own rulebase.  I would like the workers to be event driven. Server needs to be high performance, 10k to 100k+ messages per minute.  No messages can be lost from publisher to server.

I’m swinging towards using the plain api as it offers more flexibility as regarding stuff like threading/serialization/session management/security/compression but the product may be moved to Azure and offered as SaaS or PaaS, and having wcf endpoint would make sense to talk to publishers on both on/off windows, but that would be in the longer term.

Comment: This question is a bit broad too answer. Recommend that it be deleted or significantly truncated (I assume the need is no longer pertinent).

Comment: It's been a while. What did you decide on?

Comment: It would be better to split this question into multiple ones. To share a load between workers you would go for -one- durable queue shared among workers, explicit ACKs. Start simple, go with just one worker. For up to a couple hundred messages per second, your bottleneck is going to be the IO associated with processing (DB read/write, other side effects...) and nothing the broker side, especially when pre-fetching > 1.

Comment: That is an old question. I would be happy to have it split up.

Answer (score 0):

**Software Architecture is about deferring decisions, not making them upfront.**

The bindings you use should be relatively easy to change as your project progresses. Since they are an implementation detail, it's important that you define clear, concise and simple interfaces in your code, so your own code for these services depend on an abstraction of it (the interface you define), not on the concrete implementation (the code that uses the bindings, and the fact that the broker speaks amqp).

Choose the implementation that makes most sense now (keeping in mind your plans on moving to Azure) but do not marry to it.